# Python module import issue subdir

Tags: python, import, module, directory

I have the following directory structure in my Python3 project:

```
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── schemas
│   ├── collector.sql
│   └── controller.sql
├── src
│   ├── controller.db
│   ├── controller.py
│   ├── measurement_agent.py
├── tests
│   ├── regression.py
│   ├── test-invalid-mac.py
│   ├── test-invalid-url.py
│   ├── test-register-ma-json.py
│   ├── test-register-ma-return-code.py
│   ├── test-send-capabilities-return-code.py
│   ├── test-valid-mac.py
│   └── test-valid-url.py
└── todo
```

In my tests folder I have some regression tests which are ran to check the consistency of the code from src/measurement_agent.py. The problem now is that I do not want to add to my path manually the measurement_agent.py to make an import from it. I would want to know if there is any trick how to tell Python to look in my root for the import I am trying to use.

Currently I am doing:

```
import os.path

ma = os.path.abspath('..') + '/src'
sys.path.append(ma)

from measurement_agent import check_hardware_address
```

and would want to have something just like

```
from measurement_agent import check_hardware_address
```

without using any os.path tricks.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you just set `$PYTHONPATH` in the `test` target in your Makefile?

Comment: I would want to make it as seamless as possible without using any folder paths.

Comment: Then you are permanently and unfixably fried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relative imports

1. Make sure there is an `__init__.py` in all folders including the top-most (the parent)
2. Use a relative import, like this:

   `from ..src import measurement_agent`
3. Now to run your code, cd up to the parent of your parent directory and then

   `python -m parent.test.regression`

Comment: I notice you don't want to use folder paths, well I suppose my answer does use folder paths in a sense. The fact is you cannot load a python module without python knowing where the module is :) You can either make the entire thing a package (my answer) or add paths, as you already know.

Comment: It uses folders but in a more seamless way. I do not have to hard-code paths or something like this. Just the 'src' which is will be on the deployment platform.